# Populate list of data from server to tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I get an array from from server, this process is happen in the model, not controller. 
In the model, I send this array in the completion

```
completion(.success(json.content))
```

In the controller, when the controller receive this array, the delegate of the `tableView` is already called, it couldn't find the data.

In the controller, I defined an array first:

```
var articles = [Titles]()
```

Then, In the `viewDidLoad`, I get data from model and send them to `articles` array.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

      profile.showingArticles(completion: { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let list):
            self.articles = list
        case .failure(_):
            print("error")
        }
    })
}
```

As I said before, `tableView` is called earlier than it. so the `articles` return `nil`.

I don't know how I can solve it
I should send this array in `CoreData`? this is not logical to me, because this list can update every time from server, or there is an another way to send the data to `articles` before `tableview` delegate is called.

Thanks

Comment: `tableView.reloadData()`? But make sure you're updating the table in the main thread only

Comment: Thanks, but where should I add it? becuase the app first read tableview delegate and when the array is nil it crashes

Comment: I didn't see the rest of your code but I think you should add tableView.reloadData() to below profile.showingArticles and you should conform the tableView protocols such as 'numberOfRowsInSection function' and 'cellForRowAt'. You probably should assign a default number in case your array is nil in numberofrows function

Comment: Based on the assumption that `showArticles` is a asynchronous call and that the completion will be called at some point in the future AFTER `viewDidLoad` has been called, then calling `tableView.reloadData()` inside the completion handler is probably where you want to start

Comment: Thank you so much. It works :)